# Why does find_in_batches fail to include all records in a has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Given the following code

```
class Things < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sock
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
  has_many :socks, through: :things
end

class Sock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
  has_many :users, through: :things
end
```

Assuming the first user has two socks and all other users have one sock. There are 1000 users in total and 1001 socks in total. You would expect `find_in_batches` to return the same number of records as a normal select.

```
User.joins(:socks).count
=> 1001
agg = []
User.joins(:socks).find_in_batches{|g| agg += g}
agg.count
=> 1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go from the other side of the relationship, because `find_in_batches` uses primary keys to determine where to start searching for results (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id > N LIMIT 1000)

```
Sock.joins(:users).count
=> 1001
agg = []
Sock.joins(:users).find_in_batches{|g| agg += g}
agg.count
=> 1001
```